# How to help a cat with sore throat

Tags: cats, feral, domestication

I have found 2 feral cats near my house and when I approached them found that they were trying to meow but it was like  they were trying to call but not able to. Similar to sore throats in humans where voice is suppressed. I tried to feed some food but refused to eat and drank just water. I observed mucus like substance near one of the cat's bum too.
Since they are feral, they aren't easy to be taken to vet.

How do I help the cats to get back their voice? Can it be because of cold and any medications which i can mix in food so that they can get cured?

Comment: Maybe FYI how to get a stray cat into a carrier to transport it to the vet: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/26075/seeking-advice-on-managing-and-adopting-a-stray-cat/26080#26080

Comment: And if the cats drink, ypu could try to make a kind of "soup" for them (broth). You can find instuctions how to do it when searching doe "cat" and "broth" here. Then they may get more nutrition than from water only, but swallowing will be easier

Answer (score 2):

It is possible for a cat to get a sore throat. See this [link](https://cattime.com/cat-facts/health/41480-do-cats-get-sore-throat) for more information but basically the article says:

> When a feline has a sore throat, one of the most common symptoms is that the cat will start to swallow or gulp a lot. This could also include audible gulping noises.
> Other symptoms of a cat having a sore throat include drooling more than usual because swallowing might be painful, or eating and drinking less food and water than usual. When a cat has a sore throat, they might also start to meow in a much hoarser fashion than usual, just like some humans sound raspy when they have a sore throat!

Since you don't know the history of these cats, I would call the vet and see if you can get him/her to prescribe you some medication to mix into their food. If they have never been vaccinated then they may have a virus that is causing them to be sick.

Here is another [article](https://www.merckvetmanual.com/cat-owners/lung-and-airway-disorders-of-cats/pharyngitis-in-cats) about pharyngitis in cats, which could be causing the sore throat and lack of eating/drinking. If they have this then they will need an antibiotic. Hopefully if they are hungry enough, that will over power the sore throat and eventually they will eat.